# open a popup when a condition true

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, if-statement, popup

I want to open a popup when 'if' condition true
otherwise it opens normally.

But the code that I used, open the popup whether the condition is true or false.

so, help me guys and give ur views

script that I use.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
</script>
```

and the css is here.

```
<style>
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  padding-top:0px;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width:975px; 
  padding-top:0px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
   background-image: url(../Images/form_bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
```

and the div with condition.

```
<?php
        $check_crm=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from crm where party_id='$_GET[party_id]'"));
        if($check_crm>0)
        {
            ?>
        <div id="boxes">
        <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <!-- content-->
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you describe your scenario more? As we'll be able to provide a better answer as to whether you need to use AJAX or DOM manipulation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PHP doc, **[mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/mysql_query)** will return a *reference to a result*, not the result itself.

You will have to use additional methods like **mysql_num_rows()** or **mysql_fetch_assoc()** on the result reference returned by **mysql_query()**.

For example:

```
$check_crm = mysql_query("select * from crm where party_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['party_id'])."' limit 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($check_crm) > 0)
```

BTW:

- Be careful with potential **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Use at least **mysql_real_escape_string()** on user input, or better bind your variables to your queries.
- Use of old **mysql_*** PHP functions is discouraged. Use of PDO library is preferred. Check ORMs like Propel or Doctine as well.
- You can add `LIMIT 1` to your query to avoid useless processing, if your goal is to check only if *at least one match* is found in table **crm** given the **party_id**.

Comment: thanx for answer me. now it opens pop up window when condition is true but it opens another popup window when condition false.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will open the popup when the document is loaded because the it is included in the $(document).ready function. Try to include that in one function and call when the condition is true